# SVN checkout commit and update

Tags: android, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I would like to ask about `SVN checkout` with respect to  `Android`. If I commit the project and in that project I do not commit the `/bin` what will be the pros and cons related to this. What is the best practice, commit `/bin` also or not commit `/bin`.

Second question is if I commit the `/bin` along with the project and get conflict on update it what should the preferable should I resolve "*using their`s*" or resolve "*using mine*".

Comment: Its always better not to commit /bin.If you commited it accidently then its better to revert the changes with you local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin` is an auto generated folder. Whenever you import/run/debug/build a project it is recreated. While committing project to a remote repository, it is recommended not to commit **auto generated** folders (e.g., /bin, /gen)with it. Because they will be automatically created once you import/run/debug/build the project in editor.

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: Serwar thanks for your explanation i was a bit confuse about this whether to commit it or not but thanks for the clarification